# how to configure ffmpeg pipline for streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, rtmp, mediasoup

I want to get real-time streaming data (use mediasuop) and send it to nginx-rtmp-server via ffmpeg, but if I run it through the pipeline, the error occurs after logging as below. I checked that the rtmp server works well through OBS studio program, but when I run with the pipeline I prepared, the error occurs. Do you know where this problem occurs?

Problems with the pipeline? Problem with Sdp? Or something else?

my pipe line

```
ffmpeg
-loglevel
debug
-nostdin
-protocol_whitelist
file,pipe,udp,rtp,rtmp
-analyzeduration 30M
-probesize
30M
-f
sdp
-i
pipe:0
-map 0:v:0
-c:v copy -map
0:a:0 -strict -2
-c:a aac

-flags +global_headers

{filePath}.flv

-pix_fmt
yuv420p
-preset
ultrafast
-use_wallclock_as_timestamps
1
-tune zerolatency
-qmin 2
-qmax 51
-muxrate 1300k
-sdp_file {file}.sdp
-r 30
-b:v 1000k
-bufsize 3000k
-minrate 500k
-maxrate 2000k
-qscale 3
-threads 4
-b:a 128k
-framerate 30
-g 50
-crf 30
-ar 44100
-s 400x700
-f
flv

rtmp://{rtmpServerUri}
```

and my sdp file

```
    v=0
  o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
  s=FFmpeg
  c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
  t=0 0
  m=video 23490 RTP/AVP 101 
  a=rtpmap:101 VP8/90000
  a=sendonly
  m=audio 29773 RTP/AVP 100 
  a=rtpmap:100 opus/48000/2
  a=sendonly
```

and ErrorLog

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)

'  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100\n' +
  '  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100\n' +
  '  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100\n' +
  '  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100\n' +
  '  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100\n' +
  '  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0\n' +
  '  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100\n' +
  '  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100\n' +
  '  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100\n' +

"Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'
"Reading option '-nostdin' ... matched as option 'stdin' (enable or disable interaction on standard input) with argument 0"
"Reading option '-protocol_whitelist' ... matched as AVOption 'protocol_whitelist' with argument 'file,pipe,udp,rtp,rtmp'"
"Reading option '-analyzeduration' ... matched as AVOption 'analyzeduration' with argument '30M'"
"Reading option '-probesize' ... matched as AVOption 'probesize' with argument '30M'"
"Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'sdp'"
"Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'pipe:0'"
"Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0:v:0'"
"Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'"
"Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0:a:0'"
"Reading option '-strict' ..."

Routing option strict to both codec and muxer layer

matched as AVOption 'strict' with argument '-2'.
Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-flags' ... matched as AVOption 'flags' with argument '+global_header'.
Reading option '{filePath}.flv' ... matched as output url." +
Reading option '-pix_fmt' ... matched as option 'pix_fmt' (set pixel format) with argument 'yuv420p'" 
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'ultrafast'." 
Reading option '-use_wallclock_as_timestamps' ... matched as AVOption 'use_wallclock_as_timestamps' with argument '1'." 
Reading option '-tune' ... matched as AVOption 'tune' with argument 'zerolatency'." 
Reading option '-qmin' ... matched as AVOption 'qmin' with argument '2'." 
Reading option '-qmax' ... matched as AVOption 'qmax' with argument '51'." 
Reading option '-muxrate' ... matched as AVOption 'muxrate' with argument '1300k'." 
Reading option '-sdp_file' ... matched as option 'sdp_file' (specify a file in which to print sdp information) with argument '{filename}.sdp'." 
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '30'"
Reading option '-b:v' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '1000k
Reading option '-bufsize' ... matched as AVOption 'bufsize' with argument '3000k'
Reading option '-minrate' ... matched as AVOption 'minrate' with argument '500k'
Reading option '-maxrate' ... matched as AVOption 'maxrate' with argument '2000k'
Reading option '-qscale' ... matched as option 'qscale' (use fixed quality scale (VBR)) with argument '3'
Reading option '-threads' ... matched as AVOption 'threads' with argument '4
Reading option '-b:a' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '128k'
Reading option '-framerate' ... matched as AVOption 'framerate' with argument '30'
Reading option '-g' ... matched as AVOption 'g' with argument '50'
Reading option '-crf' ... matched as AVOption 'crf' with argument '30'
Reading option '-ar' ... matched as option 'ar' (set audio sampling rate (in Hz)) with argument '44100
Reading option '-s' ... matched as option 's' (set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)) with argument '400x700'
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'rtmp:{rtmpserver} ' ... matched as output url
Finished splitting the commandline.\n' +
Parsing a group of options: global .\n' +
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.\n' +
Applying option nostdin (enable or disable interaction on standard input) with argument 0.\n' +
Applying option sdp_file (specify a file in which to print sdp information) with argument {filename}.sdp
Successfully parsed a group of options
Parsing a group of options: input url pipe:0
Applying option f (force format) with argument sdp.
Successfully parsed a group of options
Opening an input file: pipe:0.
[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] Opening 'pipe:0' for reading

[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] video codec set to: vp8\n' +
[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] audio codec set to: opus\n' +
[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] audio samplerate set to: 48000\n' +
[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] audio channels set to: 2\n' +
[udp @ 0x12c610b70] end receive buffer size reported is 393216\n' +
[udp @ 0x12c610c30] end receive buffer size reported is 393216\n' +
[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] setting jitter buffer size to 500\n' +
[udp @ 0x12c611290] end receive buffer size reported is 393216\n' +
[udp @ 0x12c611330] end receive buffer size reported is 393216\n' +
[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] setting jitter buffer size to 500\n' +
[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 310 bytes read:310 seeks:0 nb_streams:2\n'

[sdp @ 0x12e008e00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: vp8, 1 reference frame, yuv420p): unspecified size\n' +
  "Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (30000000) and 'probesize' (30000000) options

'Codec AVOption qmin (minimum video quantizer scale (VBR)) specified for output file #1 (rtmp:{rtmpserver}) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream

[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] No default whitelist set
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] No default whitelist set

Starting connection attempt to {server} port 1935
[tcp @ 0x10c6054a0] Successfully connected to {server} port 1935
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] Handshaking...
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] Proto = rtmp, path = {serverpath}, app = live, fname = {filename}'
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] Window acknowledgement size = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] Max sent, unacked = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] New incoming chunk size = 4096
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] Releasing stream
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] FCPublish stream
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] Creating stream
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] Sending publish command for {filename}

Successfully opened the file

Stream mapping

Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native)
Stream #0:1 -> #1:0 (opus (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
pipe:0: Operation timed out
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:3] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
detected 8 logical cores
[graph_0_in_0_1 @ 0x10c605b50] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000
[graph_0_in_0_1 @ 0x10c605b50] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph_0_in_0_1 @ 0x10c605b50] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph_0_in_0_1 @ 0x10c605b50] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_0_in_0_1 @ 0x10c605b50] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x10c605ea0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x10c605ea0] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000|7350'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x12d204de0] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed

//// error ////

[flv @ 0x10c80aa00] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1

[AVIOContext @ 0x10c6040a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x10c6040a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] UnPublishing stream
[rtmp @ 0x11c604310] Deleting stream
[aac @ 0x10c80ce00] Qavg: nan\n']
[AVIOContext @ 0x12d005120] Statistics: 310 bytes read, 0 seeks
Conversion failed!
```

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me why not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **arealtime** in filter, best of live stream to YouTube:

```
-af asetpts=PTS/1,arealtime,asetpts=PTS*1
```

Comment: I tried, but I still get an error. ```[flv @ 0x11500aa00] dimensions not set```

Comment: add more filter for video like 4K: -vf scale=3840:-1